# Is SharePoint the flagship product of Microsoft in terms of collaboration?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, collaboration

Microsoft has a lot of enterprise applications out there. Is SharePoint their leading product in terms of collaboration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well that depends on what you mean by collaboration.

If you want to collaborate by sharing data stored in documents or list then Yes SharePoint is your product.

If you want to collaborate on creating documents with simultaneous editing then [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/) is your product.

If you want to collaborate by sharing knowledge in the form of discussions, then [Yammer](https://www.yammer.com/) is your product.

If you want to collaborate using e-mail then outlook/exchange is your product.

All of this is combined in [Office 365](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/), so that's probably what should be called the leading Microsoft collaboration "product".

Comment: Nicely explained. I always make sure to read your answers/comments. There is so much to learn from them.